# Who changes the foreground process group of a terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

Let's say I have opened a terminal window that uses `bash`. The process group that `bash` belongs to is the foreground process group of the terminal.

Now let's say I opened `cat` in the terminal, what will happen is that a new process group will be created and `cat` will belong to this process group, **and this process group will now become the foreground process group of the terminal**.

When `cat` terminates and execution returns to `bash`, **the process group that `bash` belongs to will again becomes the foreground process group of the terminal**.

My question is: how did the foreground process group of the terminal changed in these two times, who changed it?

Comment: Bash did. See last paragraph of Gilles's answer